The "Create Custom Filter" button doesn't work in custom filter pages unless uqlId query parameter is removed
The "Create Custom Filter" button is supposed to toggle the custom filter controls, and it does... except when the page URL has a uqlId=XXXXX query parameter, which is what happens when you click into an existing custom filter from the right sidebar. With uqlId=XXXXX, the click event listener isn't even there. If I change the number to some other random value that isn't one of my tag filters, then the click event listener is there.
Ex. I click into my VS Code custom filter, which in my right sidebar has the href https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?uqlId=63959. Once I get a redirect to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code+or+vscode-tasks+or+vscode-debugger?sort=Newest&filters=NoAcceptedAnswer&uqlId=63959, the "Create Custom Filter" does nothing. And then if I navigate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code+or+vscode-tasks+or+vscode-debugger?sort=Newest&filters=NoAcceptedAnswer, the button works.

How exactly did you stumble upon this? o_O

@KarlKnechtel okay it's less weird than I thought. see edit. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?uqlId=63959 is just the URL in my sidebar for my VS Code custom tag filter.
